# Update Multiple DataGrids in WPF for Header Title

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form that has a dynamic amount of datagrids that are brought in programmatically each one on a new tabpage.

My problem is that I need to change the Header of each column. I have tried doing it through a method

```
DataGridForSupplier.Columns[0].Header = "123";
```

but that keeps crashing with an error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Turns out the problem is that the grid wasn't finished loading. So after waiting for all tabpage to load and add data to all the grids , even then the code

```
DataGridForSupplier.Columns[0].Header = "123";
```

would still crash. If the tabs are left to load on their own with no header tampering then the datagrid shows fine.

I would just LOVE to do this in XAML problem is that seeing that I don't know how many grids will load at run time I tried doing this at the back. So I'm open to any solution at this point. I tried finding a solution that would incorporate something that would 'theme' all the datagrids. Luckily all the datagrids headers will repeat across all tabs. So header 1 on tabpage 1 - 10 will be the same. Header 2 on tabpage 1 - 10 will be the same

Something like

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeaderNameText, RelativeSource=>> RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" /> 
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

but this needs to repeat for every Grid. This seems to escape me at the moment.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: One way to do is to disable AutogenerateColumns in all datagrid, when you find the data items to the grid, it will populate based on the object property name for each column. You can put an alias to the property name as well.

Comment: I tried disabling the AutoGen but did not much help to point me in the correct direction.  It seems that you can apply an overall theme to all datagrids through XAML but I am not sure how this is done. To ask this a different way how can I adjust the col name for each col 1 of every datagrid header to lets say "Found" through XAML if I can pass the datagrid name to XAML

Comment: I did also try to change the header in the datatable before it is bound to the datagrid  but this poses another error for some reason down the line seems like a special char is not allowed in the header and this is strange because  it is the 2nd comma in the string similar to "this,name," and I dont think changing it in the datatable is the best way to proceed anyway. Seems the best place is in XAML

Answer (score 0):

A rather lengthy answer, but this solution does not require any additional libraries, 3rd party tools, etc. You can expand it as you want later such as for adding hooks to mouse-move/over/drag/drop/focus, etc.  First the premise on subclassing which I found out early in my learning WPF.  You can not subclass a xaml file, but can by a .cs code file.  In this case, I subclassed the DataGrid to MyDataGrid.  Next, I created an interface for a known control type to ensure contact of given functions/methods/properties.  I have stripped this version down to cover just what you need to get.

The interface below is just to expose any class using this interface MUST HAVE A METHOD called MyDataGridItemsChanged and expects a parameter of MyDataGrid.. easy enough

```
public interface IMyDataGridSource
{
   void MyDataGridItemsChanged(MyDataGrid mdg);
}
```

Now, declaring in-code a MyDataGrid derived from DataGrid.  In this class, I am adding a private property of type IMyDataGridSource to grab at run-time after datagrids are built and bound.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
   // place-holder to keep if so needed to expand later
   IMyDataGridSource boundToObject;

   public MyDataGrid()
   {
      // Force this class to trigger itself after the control is completely loaded,
      // bound to whatever control and is ready to go
      Loaded += MyDataGrid_Loaded;
   }

   private void MyDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      // when the datacontext binding is assigned or updated, see if it is based on 
      // the IMyDataGridSource object.  If so, try to type-cast it and save into the private property
      // in case you want to add other hooks to it directly, such as mouseClick, grid row changed, etc...
      boundToObject = DataContext as IMyDataGridSource;
   }

   // OVERRIDE the DataGrid base class when items changed and the ItemsSource
   // list/binding has been updated with a new set of records    
   protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // do whatever default behavior
      base.OnItemsChanged(e);

      // if the list is NOT bound to the data context of the IMyDataGridSource, get out
      if (boundToObject == null)
         return;

      // the bound data context IS of expected type... call method to rebuild column headers
      // since the "boundToObject" is known to be of IMyDataGridSource,
      // we KNOW it has the method... Call it and pass this (MyDataGrid) to it
      boundToObject.MyDataGridItemsChanged(this);
   }
}
```

Next into your form where you put the data grid.  You will need to add an "xmlns" reference to your project so you can add a "MyDataGrid" instead of just "DataGrid".  In my case, my application is called "StackHelp" as this is where I do a variety of tests from other answers offered.  The "xmlns:myApp" is just making an ALIAS "myApp" to the designer to it has access to the classes within my application.  Then, I can add

```
<Window x:Class="StackHelp.MyMainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:myApp="clr-namespace:StackHelp" 
   Title="Main Window" Height="700" Width="900">

   <StackPanel>
      <!-- adding button to the main window to show forced updated list only -->
      <Button Content="Refresh Data" Width="100" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click" />

      <myApp:MyDataGrid 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="True" />

   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now, into the MyMainWindow.cs code-behind

```
namespace StackHelp
{
   public partial class MyMainWindow : Window
   {
      // you would have your own view model that all bindings really go to
      MyViewModel VM;

      public MyMainWindow()
      {
         // Create instance of the view model and set the window binding 
         // to this public object's DataContext
         VM = new MyViewModel();
         DataContext = VM;

         // Now, draw the window and controls
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      // for the form button, just to force a refresh of the data.
      // you would obviously have your own method of querying data and refreshing.
      // I am not obviously doing that, but you have your own way to do it.
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         // call my viewmodel object to refresh the data from whatever
         // data origin .. sql, text, import, whatever
         VM.Button_Refresh();
      }
   }
}
```

Finally to my sample ViewModel which incorporates the IMyDataGridSource

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyDataGridSource, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }

   public ObservableCollection<OneItem> ItemsCollection { get; set; } 
      = new ObservableCollection<OneItem>();


   public void Button_Refresh()
   {
      ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<OneItem>
      {
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Sunday", DayOfWeek = 0},
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Monday", DayOfWeek = 1},
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Tuesday", DayOfWeek = 2},
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Wednesday", DayOfWeek = 3},
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Thursday", DayOfWeek = 4},
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Friday", DayOfWeek = 5 },
         new OneItem{ DayName = "Saturday", DayOfWeek = 6 }
      };
      RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsCollection");      
   }


   // THIS is the magic hook exposed that will allow you to rebuild your
   // grid column headers
   public void MyDataGridItemsChanged(MyDataGrid mdg)
   {
      // if null or no column count, get out.
      // column count will get set to zero if no previously set grid
      // OR when the items grid is cleared out. don't crash if no columns
      if (mdg == null)
         return;

      mdg.Columns[0].Header = "123";
   }
}
```

Now, taking this a step further.  I don't know how you manage your view models and you may have multiple grids in your forms and such.  You could create the above MyViewModel class as a smaller subset such as MyDataGridManager class.  So each datagrid is bound to its own MyDataGridManager instance.  It has its own querying / populating list for the grid, handling its own rebuild column headers, mouse clicks (if you wanted to expand), record change selected, etc.

Hope this helps you some.  Again, this does not require any other 3rd party libraries and you can extend as you need.  I have personally done this and more to the data grid and several other controls for certain specific pattern handling.